# default constructor for main program vs vb.net default

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hello everyone i'm new to c# language i was use vb.net
vb.net code:

```vb
Module Module1 ' main static class
    Sub Main()
        ' output: constructor will be excuted
    End Sub
    Sub New()
        Console.WriteLine("constructor will be excuted")
    End Sub
End Module
```

but when i use c# the default constructor of class Program is Never executed

```
class Program   
{

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       // no output
   }
    public Program()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("c# the default constructor of class Program is Never executed");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not executed because `Main` is executed as a static method, no instance of `Program` is created.

You can make your constructor static if you'd like, however it's likely you don't need the constructor at all, and you can move all your typical constructor code into `Main`

Comment: but also in vb.net the constructor is executed Although I did not create an object

Comment: @NourAhmed As far as I'm aware, `Module` is equivalent to a static class in C# - so that's why the constructor is called (it's a static constructor being called) while your C# code is an instance constructor.